# Could not load symbol clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties : Не найдена указанная процедура

Tags: android, unity3d, canvas

Unity. кода нет совсем, исключительно Image и Canvas. Все, пишет при операции Build

Comment: Текст ошибки то скиньте

Comment: В интернете есть много ответов на эту ошибку. Вы их читали? [Первое](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unsure-if-unity-or-oculus-issue-could-not-load-symbol-ovrp_initialize5.599659/), [второе](https://www.cyberforum.ru/unity/thread2685314.html) и [и так далее](https://yandex.ru/search/?clid=2186621&text=Could%20not%20load%20symbol%20clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties%20%3A%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0&lr=9&redircnt=1603532713.1)